# Updating and Saving in same php file

Tags: php

im trying to update a value of the variable home all in the same php file, mas 
the value of the variable have to be saved in this same file, is it possible? How can i make it?

I already been trying some tricks but no sucess, hope someone already passed whit the same problem i had.

```
<?php
$home = 'home';
?>
<form method="post" name="" action="" >
<label><?php echo $home;?></label>
<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $home;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="" value="Gravar" />
</form>
```

Comment: So you want to update the value of `$home` variable using that form, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but you could use a $_POST or $_GET variable to set the $home variable dynamically.

EDIT:

To save the $home variable you can do this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['home_variable'])){
    //save it
}

if(empty($_POST['home'])){
    $home = 'home';
} else {
    $home = $_POST['home'];
}

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $ SERVER['PHP SELF']; ?>" >
<label><?php echo $home; ?></label>
<input type="text" name="home" value="<?php echo $home;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="home_variable" value="<?php echo $home; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Gravar" />
</form>
```

Comment: But the data of the variable home needs to be saved. I have to be abble some how rewrite the variable data.

Comment: If you need to save the $home variable then you could use a hidden input and save when for form is submitted. Please see the code above.

Comment: the problem @danielwest is this doesnt save it in the php file, if a refresh the page it gets the data before

Comment: @mauro I don't understand what you are trying to do? You can't save anything in a PHP file. You have to save the data in a database or flat file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['home'])) {

    $var = addcslashes(htmlentities($_POST['home']), "'");
    $fileContent = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $fileContent = preg_replace("/^(\\\$home ?= ?)'(.*)'(;[\n\r])/m", "$1'$var'$3", $fileContent);

    file_put_contents(__FILE__, $fileContent);
    // redirect to skip post in next refresh
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
    exit;
}

$home = 'home';

?>
<form method="post" name="" action="" >
<label><?php echo $home;?></label>
<input type="text" name="home" value="<?php echo $home;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="" value="Gravar" />
</form>
```

Comment: please read my post, i need the value rewrite/update in the same php file.

Comment: Sorry, Mauro, not catched this. I have updated a code to be updated himself. Please make sure that the user, under which is run web server can write into a file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using 2 files:

set.php and take.php

set.php - the file where you set up the $home variable

take.php the file where $home is placed, and can be taken

set.php:

```
<form action="set.php" method="POST">
Home:<input type="text" name="home"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['home'])){
$home=$_POST['home'];
$content= '<?php $home = "'.$home.'"; ?>';

    $file = "take.php";
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

This script takes the value from the form, and places it in a variable in take.php file. An example of take.php file:

```
<?php $home = "nowhere"; ?>
```